# Custom Binary Search Function is not Working Properly

Tags: java, loops, binary-search

I am creating a custom binary search function and am running into issues. I have looked through the code for a good while now, however,  I cannot figure out why nothing is returning. Please let me know what you think. Thank you!

a is the array, b is the result that is returned in the end, and t is the target value. Pos is the current position and min and max are the minimum and maximum positions.

```
public static int binarySearch(int a[], int t){
    int min = 0;
    int max = a.length;
    if (a[0] == t){
        return 0;
    }
    int b = -1;
    for (int pos = min; a[pos] != t;){
        pos = (max - min) / 2;
        if (a[pos] == t){
            b = pos;
        } else {
            if(t > a[pos]){
                min = pos + 1;
            } else {
                min = pos - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you tried?  Have you tried printing out the values in the loop?

Comment: `t`, `a`, `b` are meaningless: they make your code hard to read: http://www.makinggoodsoftware.com/2009/05/04/71-tips-for-naming-variables/

Answer (score 2):

Two small issues

```
pos = (max - min) / 2;
```

It looks like you're trying to find the average of the values, but are instead finding half the difference

Instead to find the average, use `pos = (max - min) / 2 + min;`

Also when moving the `max` down, you accidentally move the `min` up instead

`min = pos - 1;` should instead be `max = pos - 1;`

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues with your code :

1. Your loop condition is not enough to determine the termination of the whole process . Your loop condition is `a[pos] != t` and you only increase or decrease the `pos` which will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`eventually if the element we search can't be found inside the array.
2. Your if-else is not correct , cause you only update the value for the **min** and not the max too.
3. Instead of 'moving' the value `pos` by half each time, you just set it the average of min and max which is not correct.

Combine all the above and you will get this result :

```
public static int binarySearch(int a[], int t) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = a.length;

    if (a[0] == t) {
        return 0;
    }
    int b = -1;
    for (int pos = min; a[pos] != t;) {
        pos = min + (max - min) / 2;

        if (pos >= a.length || pos <= 0) {
            break;
        }

        if (a[pos] == t) {
            b = pos;
        } else {
            if (t > a[pos]) {
                min = pos + 1;
            } else {
                max = pos - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return b;
}
```